# A determinant with an interesting construction

Tags: determinant

Find the following determinant $$\left| \begin{matrix}x_1&a&a&...&a\\ a&x_2&a&...&a\\a&a&x_3&...&a\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a&a&a&...&x_n \end{matrix} \right|$$

I decided to subtract the last row from all other rows to get $$\left| \begin{matrix}x_1-a&0&0&...&a-x_n\\ 0&x_2-a&0&...&a-x_n\\0&0&x_3-a&...&a-x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a&a&a&...&x_n \end{matrix} \right|$$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Why are there zeros below the $a-x_n$?

Comment: @Tbw, sorry, missed that!

Comment: From there, see what you can get from the formal definition of the determinant using permutations. Which permutations don't hit zeros? Which of those are even and odd?

Answer (score 3):

Let $g : x \mapsto \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n (x_k-x)$. For any $b,x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $$A_b(x)=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+x&a+x&a+x&...&a+x\\ b+x&x_2+x&a+x&...&a+x\\b+x&b+x&x_3+x&...&a+x\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\b+x&b+x&b+x&...&x_n+x \end{pmatrix}$$

It is easy to see that the function $f : x \mapsto \det(A_b(x))$ is a polynomial function of degree $1$ (you can see this by substracting the first column to all the other columns, and then develop the determinant w.r.t the first column).

But one has directly $\displaystyle f(-a)=g(a)$ and $\displaystyle f(-b)=g(b)$, so for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $b \neq a$, one has
$$f(x)=\dfrac{f(-b)-f(-a)}{-b+a}(x+a)+f(-a) = -\dfrac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a}(x+a) +g(a)$$

which gives (still for $b \neq a$)
$$\det(A_b(0))=f(0) =g(a) -a\dfrac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a} $$

Now, since $b \mapsto \det(A_b(0))$ is polynomial, then it is continuous, so $\displaystyle \det(A_a(0))=\lim_{b \rightarrow a} \det(A_b(0))$.

One gets
$$\det(A_a(0))=g(a)-g'(a)a$$

i.e. finally
$$\boxed{\begin{vmatrix}x_1&a&a&...&a\\ a&x_2&a&...&a\\a&a&x_3&...&a\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a&a&a&...&x_n \end{vmatrix} = \prod_{k=1}^n (x_k-a) + a \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{l=1, l\neq k}^n (x_l-a)}$$

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to present an alternative approach using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). Your matrix can be written in the form $D + axx^T$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix and $x$ the column-vector given by
$$
D = \pmatrix{x_1 - a\\ & \ddots \\ && x_n - a}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1 \\ \vdots \\ 1}.
$$
We have
$$
\det(D + axx^T) = (1 + ax^TD^{-1}x)\det(D).
$$
We calculate
$$
\det(D) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (x_i - a),\quad x^TD^{-1}x = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{x_i - a}.
$$
Thus, we have the following formula for the determinant:
$$
\det(D + axx^T) = \left(1 + a\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{x_i - a} \right)\prod_{i = 1}^n (x_i - a),
$$
which can be further simplified to yield TheSilverDoe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D_a(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ be the determinant, then

$$
D_a(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1-a) D_a(x_2,\dots,x_n)+(-1)^n (a-x_n)(-1)^{n-1} a \prod\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} (x_i - a),
$$
as follows from [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). This simplifies into
$$
 = (x_1 -a)D_a(x_2,\dots,x_n) + a \prod\limits_{i=2}^{n} (x_i-a).
$$
With the base case $D_a(x_n) = x_n$. After expanding $D_a(x_2,\dots,x_n)$ up to $D_a(x_k,\dots,x_n)$ we get
$$
= \prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} (x_i-a) D_a(x_k,\dots,x_n) +a\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} \prod\limits_{i\neq j} (x_i-a),
$$
which can be proven by induction. Expanding it all the way up to $D_a(x_n)$, we get
$$
=x_n \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i-a) + a\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} \prod\limits_{i\neq j}(x_i-a).
$$
This then simplifies into a symmetric form from @TheSilverDoe answer:
$$
= \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-a) + a \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \prod\limits_{i\neq j} (x_i-a),
$$
which, assuming $a \not\in\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ can be further refactored as
$$
=\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{a}{x_j-a}\right) \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-a),
$$

or as $P(a) - a P'(a)$ for $P(a) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-a)$.